# Can I donate a kidney later and recieve one now?

Tags: kidney, organ-donation

The [kidney voucher](http://transplants.ucla.edu/site.cfm?id=406) allows one to donate a kidney now and get a kidney coupon which they give to a friend or family member, which they can redeem for a kidney later.

Is the reverse possible? Can I agree to donate a kidney later, and get a kidney voucher now (for someone else, of course)?

Comment: Why ask here when you can call the site you linked to?

Answer (score 2):

*"for someone else, of course"*

Of course not. You haven't read or understood the rules. The point is that you donate a kidney and then the **intended recipient** gets a voucher to redeem **your** kidney in the future. The vouchers are not transferrable and only exist to enable someone to donate a kidney for someone else at a time that suits them but not have the recipient immediately take it. i.e. You know someone who will lose kidney function in the future and are happy to donate now, rather than in the future emergency situation when they need it.

Even if you were right about the transferability of the voucher, **what you are asking is very unethical. Take a good hard look at your moral compass.**

> 1. A renal allograft can only be provided to the pre-determined intended recipient(s) identified in the consent forms.
> 2. The 'voucher' expires when the intended recipient is no longer living.
> 3. The 'voucher' may not be reassigned.
> 4. The donor may not withdraw the 'voucher' from the intended recipient after kidney donation.
> 5. The intended recipient may only redeem the 'voucher' when transplantation is indicated as a therapeutic modality for end-stage
>      kidney disease (ESKD).
> 6. If the NKR was to undergo a change of control, the surviving organization must honor all 'voucher' liabilities with the same or
>      better capacity to fulfill all outstanding 'voucher' obligations.
>
> In order to avoid the transfer of ‘vouchers’ for monetary gain,
>   redemption must be limited to the intended recipient as identified in
>   the informed consent document. The intended recipient is required to
>   have government photo identification. To further insure that the
>   patient receiving the ‘voucher’ kidney is the same person identified
>   on the original consent forms, blood typing and tissue typing is
>   confirmed before the ‘voucher’ is redeemed

Comment: The "someone else" is a friend at church that needs a kidney transplant now, but I'm going on a trip for two years. The "someone else" is them. I meant that I can't donate a kidney and then get a kidney for myself.

Comment: Also "gets a voucher to redeem **your** kidney in the future" is a blatant error. Kidneys don't last that long

Comment: seriously, the website you linked has a form and phone number you can call to ask your questions.